# jquery and javascript native

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

am currently studying jquery, can someone tell me the things that javascript native can do which jquery cannot ?

Comment: technically incorrect to call javascript native code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: **nothing**

jQuery is an abstraction layer on top of plain JavaScript, it **is** JavaScript, it just adds a bunch of shortcuts to common tasks, usually in a highly optimized and cross-browser way.

It doesn't take anything away, you can mix and match all you want, jQuery simply **adds** to your options.

I'd take a look at the [jQuery getting started documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) for more questions you might have like this.

Comment: @Downvoter - Helps to mention why, if you don't mention why you think an answer is incorrect, it helps no-one...

Comment: Your check is in the mail, Nick. :)

Comment: Hmmm, I think that this requires looking at what is lost, which I would say is that speed hit from including jquery.  Which makes caching via google's CDN hosting of jQuery a useful tactic.  There's always a tradeoff, is the point.

Comment: @Tchalvak good point, but how is that related to anything on this thread?

Comment: Yes.  What native javascript can do that jQuery cannot is: avoid the need to include the hit of that library download and any subsequent processor-use overhead.  Personally I don't consider that a worthwhile tipping factor, but it may be important for performance considerations.

Comment: @Tchalvak - However the browser is generally smart enough to not download an unchanged file again and again.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a library for Javascript which adds additional features.
It doesn't replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

None i think. But there maybe some things that jQuery can do but JavaScript cannot.

Comment: jQuery _is_ Javascript.  By definition, there is nothing that jQuery can do that Javascript cannot.